# How does "makeAddFunction" in Eloquent JS work?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to learn Javascript by reading [Eloquent Javacript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/contents.html). I'm on the [chapter dealing with functions](http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter3.html) and I'm stuck trying to figure out how the code below works. I don't see how the add function ever gets called. I see them calling addTwo and addFive but those names are different than add. The result of this code being run is 9. Can someone please explain this to me.

```
 function makeAddFunction(amount) {

     function add(number) {

         return number + amount;
     }

     return add;
 }

 var addTwo = makeAddFunction(2);

 var addFive = makeAddFunction(5);

 show(addTwo(1) + addFive(1));
```

Comment: That's ok. google "javascript closures". it has too many resources on the web for us to start explain.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work?rq=1

Comment: Ohh, exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116011/javascript-example-question-lexical-scoping-closure-eloquent-javascript?rq=1

Comment: possible duplicate of [Syntax of Closures](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17982637/syntax-of-closures)

Answer (score 1):

In `makeAddFunction`, a function is created, called `add`. This function is returned.

`makeAddFunction` is called twice with 2 different parameters, and stored in two variables, `addTwo` and `addFive`.

Calling `addTwo()` and `addFive()` is calling the functions created by `add()`, with the "amounts" 2 and 5 respectively.

```
addTwo(1) + addFive(1) == (1 + 2) + (1 + 5) == 9
```

Sometimes these types of 'closures' are called Builders, or Factories. The `makeAddFunction` 'builds' a special version of `add` based on the parameter you pass to `makeAddFunction`.

The `addTwo` function would look like:

```
function addTwo(number) {
    return number + 2;
}
```

Comment: "indirectly" was probably poor word choice.

Comment: This does not explain HOW the code works.  It merely translates the code to English.

Comment: Generally explaining code involves translating it into English in a logical manner...

Comment: I can see how they arrive at the number 9 but I still don't understand how addTwo and addFive pass the value 1 to the add function. I'm not even sure if I'm explaining it correct for you to understand what I'm not understanding.

Comment: For example: when they say var addTwo = makeAddFunction(2); I can see that the value 2 is being set as the argument "amount" because they called the function by it's correct name which is makeAddFunction. I don't understand how the value 1 is being set as the argument "number" in  show(addTwo(1) + addFive(1)); because the function is called add, it's not called addTwo or addFive?

Answer (score 0):

The `makeAddFunction` create a closure that sets `amount` as whatever number you pass in and returns a function that will add that amount to whatever number you pass to the new function and return it.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the SO *Linked/Related Questions* on the right. Anyway ..

This is explained the article, albeit with a lot of fluff. Anyway, with a bit of fluff-cutting here is a "annotated" version:

> .. functions [do] not just package up [some code to run], but also an environment. [..] a function defined inside another function retains access [to lexical variables (like "amount")] that existed in [the outer function] at the point when [the inner function] was defined.
>
> Thus, the [inner] `add` function in the above example, which is created when makeAddFunction is called, captures an environment [including the "amount" variable of the outer function]. It packages this environment, together with [the code to run], into a value [(which is a fancy way to say functions are just objects)], which is then returned from the outer function.
>
> When this returned function ([which has been assigned to] `addTwo` and `addFive`) is called, [the called function has access to] the captured environment ([and the "amount" variable which still contains the value initially passed to `makeAddFunction`]). These two values ([which are currently named by] "amount" and "number") are then added, and the result is returned.

I am not found of the original usage of "value" and have edit those parts a good bit - in JavaScript, *variables* (not *values*) are bound in closures.

Answer (score 0):

My best advice is you try to learn a bit about Javascript closures. Really. I might not be the answer you are looking for, but it is the best you can do if you want to understand what's happening there.

Get yourself a copy of any good javascript book. Let me suggest 'Javascript - The Good Parts' by Douglas Crockford.

For some of us, Javascript closures were not something we grokked. I hope it's easier for you.

Anyway, `makeAddFunction`is a function creator. It creates new functions which are tied to the parameter you passed to `makeAddFunction`. Therefore, the `addTwo` variable receives and stores a new function, which you can invoke later by appending parentheses to it, i.e. `addTwo()`.

The parameter you pass to `addTwo`, i.e. `1`on invokation `addTwo(1)` is passed to the `add` function, because `addTwo` is nothing more than an `add` function where the `amount` var has a fix value of `2`.

Answer (score 0):

`var addTwo = makeAddFunction(2);`

When you call `makeAddFunction(2)` initially, the `amount` var is within its function scope where `add` can see it. `addTwo` now is set to the `add` function that `makeAddFunction(2)` returned.

`addTwo(1)`

Remember `addTwo` is now set to what `makeAddFunction(2)` returned, which is the function `add`, and `amount` is set to 2 within `makeAddFunction(2)`'s scope. `add` just returns its argument (1), plus the `amount` (2) in  `makeAddFunction(2)`'s scope.

The same goes for `addFive(5)`.

Javascript Ninja or The Good Parts are good reads that explain closures in detail. I'd highly suggest picking up those.

Answer (score -1):

Javascript relies pretty heavily on higher-order functions.  Functions can be returned, assigned to variables, and passed around as values.  This comes in handy in a lot of situations, especially when dealing with evented programming (JS's direct lineage from the its most prolific implementation in the browser.)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function

What you are seeing is a function that creates a function.  It could be considered a "factory" for a function with one preset argument.

Comment: Function does not return a closure. it creates it. ( and im not the downvoter)